# Spark GraphX get Shortest path between two vertices with specified depth

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, spark-graphx

I am new to GraphX, here is the question:

we have two known vertex id verteices:
id1
id2

and set the depth to traverse:
depth=4

how to get the shortest path info from id1 to id2 with the limited traverse depth value to 4, it seems need to implement with pregel programing model, can anyone give me a scala code sample?

Thank you so much